# How can i remove things in a for loop?

Tags: php

so thats my code and i know i have to put a for loop inside a for loop to get what i want.(very new to programming so dont blame me lmao)

```
   <?php include('includes/header.php'); ?>

<div class="middlecontainer">
    <?php
    for ($i=0; $i<=10; $i++) {
        for ($j=0; $j<=10; $j++) {

            echo '*';
        }
        echo '<br />';
    }

    for ($i = 10;$i >= 10; $i--){

        for ($i = $i; $i >=0; $i--){

            echo "*";
        }
        echo "<br />";
    }
    ?>
</div>
<?php include('includes/footer.php'); ?>
```

```
***********
***********
***********
***********
***********
***********
***********
***********
***********
***********
***********
```

thats what it looks like but i want it like that:

```
***********
*         *
*         *
*         *
*         *
*         *
*         *
*         *
*         *
*         *
*         *
***********
```

Can someone tell me how i can make it to look like this?

Comment: Use conditional rendering with if

Comment: you have to put an if check before your echo. There you check if you are in the first or last line I guess i==0 or i == 10 and you have to check if you are in the first or last column if you are not in the first or last line ... something like j==0 or j ==10

Comment: Can you care enough to address the answers and if they really helped solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
for($i=0; $i<=10; $i++) {
   for($j=0; $j<=10; $j++) {
      if($i==0||$i==10) {
         echo '*';
      }
      else {
        if($j==0||$j==10) {
           echo '*';
        }
        else {
            echo ' ';
        }
     }
   }
   echo '<br />';
}
```

or if you don't care about readabilty,

```
for($i=0; $i<=10; $i++) {
    for($j=0; $j<=10; $j++) {
        echo  $i==0||$i==10||$j==0||$j==10 ? '*' :' ';
    }
    echo '<br />';
}
```

should also do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Only one nested loop is enough. If the current row is between first and last(both exclusive) and if the current column is between first and last(both exclusive), then print a space, else print the asterisk(`*`).

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$N = 10;

for ($i = 1; $i <= $N; $i++) {
    for ($j = 1; $j <= $N; $j++) {
        echo $j > 1 && $j < $N && $i > 1 && $i < $N ? ' ' : '*';
    }
    echo PHP_EOL; // or echo "<br/>";
}
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onlinephp.io/c/8a2f5)